# prime number function with nested loop in R gives incorrect results

Tags: r, for-loop, debugging, nested-loops, primes

I need to make a function that returns a vector of all prime numbers from 3 to n. I know there are easier ways to make a function determining if a number is prime or not, but I was specifically asked to use 2 loop.
my function:

```
prime.numbers = function(n= 100){
  l=c()
  for (i in 3:n){
    for (j in 2:ceiling(sqrt(i))){
      if ((i %% j )== 0) {
        break      }
      else{ l= append(l,i)}
    }  }
  return(l)}

prime.numbers()
```

for the example of n = 100 I got:

```
  [1]  3  5  5  7  7  9 11 11 11 13 13 13 15 17 17 17 17 19 19 19 19 21 23 23 23 23
 [27] 25 25 25 27 29 29 29 29 29 31 31 31 31 31 33 35 35 35 37 37 37 37 37 37 39 41
 [53] 41 41 41 41 41 43 43 43 43 43 43 45 47 47 47 47 47 47 49 49 49 49 49 51 53 53
 [79] 53 53 53 53 53 55 55 55 57 59 59 59 59 59 59 59 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 63 65 65
[105] 65 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 69 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 73 73 73 73 73 73 73 73
[131] 75 77 77 77 77 77 79 79 79 79 79 79 79 79 81 83 83 83 83 83 83 83 83 83 85 85
[157] 85 87 89 89 89 89 89 89 89 89 89 91 91 91 91 91 93 95 95 95 97 97 97 97 97 97
[183] 97 97 97 99
```

which is obviously wrong. I get an increasing number of the same value for some reason, and some of it isn't even a prime number.

can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
thank you

Comment: just add `break` after  your append statement - if you already identified that it is a prime number no need to continue the inner loop.

Answer (score 6):

Don't `append` the number within your second `for` loop, do it as the result of a comparison after the `j` loop. The reason? For every number between `2` and `ceiling(sqrt(i))`, you are making the comparison, and for each of them; I believe you intend to do that only once per `i`, not per `j`.

Instead, move the `append` to the end of the first loop, and do another comparison before `append`ing it.

```r
prime_number <- function(n = 100) {
  l = c()
  for (i in 3:n){
    for (j in 2:ceiling(sqrt(i))){
      if ((i %% j) == 0) break
    }
    if ((i %% j) != 0) { l = append(l,i); }
  }
  l
}
prime_number()
#  [1]  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set a toggle `prime <- TRUE`. If a composite(non-prime) number is encountered, switch it off as `prime <- FALSE` and `break`. In the end of the inner loop, if the `prime` toggle is still `TRUE`, append the number `i` to the output vector.

```r
prime.numbers = function(n = 100) {
  l <- c()
  for (i in 3:n) {
    prime <- TRUE
    for (j in 2:ceiling(sqrt(i))) {
      if (i %% j == 0) { prime <- FALSE; break }
    }
    if(prime) l <- append(l, i)
  }
  return(l)
}

prime.numbers()
# [1]  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, you should append the number to the list after the nested for, only once, when you verified that it's not divisible for any number.

Your code instead appends it every time it founds a divisor that does not return 0 for i %% j, which could happen more than once for a given number, even if other checks fail. This sums up your code symptoms.